# Raspberry pi adc: MPC3001 using python and spidev

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, adc

I am trying to use a MPC3001 ADC with the Raspberry pi over SPI using Python.
While doing so I am getting some strange results:

The code I am using:

```
import sys
import spidev

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)

def readAdc(channel):
    r = spi.xfer2([1, 8 + channel << 4, 0])
    return ((r[1]&3) << 8) + r[2]

while True:
    print readAdc(0)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

running the script above, while measuring the center point of a voltage divider, yields a random switching between 2 values: 504 and 1016.

Since 504 is the value I would expect to be correct, in combination with the binary representation of the two results;

504 --> 00111111000

1016 --> 01111111000

I assume I am accidentally 'creating' a 1 somewhere.

Can someone point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance

BTW: Is it me, or is there no decent documentation for the spidev lib?

Answer (score 1):

In the [data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21293b.pdf) figure 5-2 it shows what the issue is.  The data returned from the device, bit by bit, looks like this (where X = don't care, and Bx is bit number x of the data; B0 is LSB and B9 MSB):

```
BYTE0:  X  X  0 B9 B8 B7 B6 B5 
BYTE1: B4 B3 B2 B1 B0 B1 B2 B3
BYTE2: B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9  X  X
```

If you change the return statement to this:

```
return ((r[0] & 0x1F) << 5) | ((r[1] >> 3) & 0x1F)
```

it might work.

But if I were you I wouldn't trust me (I no longer have a hardware setup where I could test anything).  I think it's best to print the individual values of the bytes in r and ponder the result until it starts to make sense.  Be aware that some SPI implementations let you read in the data on either the rising or the falling edge.  If you have that wrong your data will never make sense.

Another clue here is that the three LSBs of an A/D converter reading shouldn't be consistently 000, for reading after reading.  There is almost always noise in the least significant bit, at least, if not two or three bits.

BTW I agree with you about spidev.  I switched to quick2wire and then things went much more smoothly.  It's better written and much better documented.

Comment: Err, I think instead of using bitwise and (&) when combining the bits from each byte in "return ((r[0] & 0x1F) << 5) & ((r[1] >> 3) & 0x1F)" (which will always return 0 as the two values will never have overlapping 1s) you should use bitwise or (|)), i.e. "return ((r[0] & 0x1F) << 5) | ((r[1] >> 3) & 0x1F)"

Comment: Yes, amended the post.